# How to get the amount of extra hours registered for each day reported in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

Having an attendance report which displays the entrance, lunch time exit, lunch time entrance and final exit for each user, I need to display the extra hours worked counting only the time after 20:30 and limited to 21:30.

i.e. 
if a worker reports its exit around 20:10 it shouldn't count as extra time.

if a worker reports its exit around 21:00 it should count as extra time.

if a worker reports its exit after 21:30 it should only count as extra time until 21:30.

Having the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblassistance` (
`Entrance` datetime NOT NULL,
`LunchExit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`LunchEntrance` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`DayExit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`UserID` int(11) NOT NULL);


INSERT INTO tblassistance(Entrance, LunchExit, LunchEntrance, DayExit, UserID) VALUES ('2019-01-05 14:30:00','2019-01-05 15:30:00','2019-01-05 16:30:00','2019-01-05 21:30:00', '1');

INSERT INTO tblassistance(Entrance, LunchExit, LunchEntrance, DayExit, UserID) VALUES ('2019-01-05 14:30:00','2019-01-05 15:30:00','2019-01-05 16:30:00','2019-01-05 21:36:00', '2');

INSERT INTO tblassistance(Entrance, LunchExit, LunchEntrance, DayExit, UserID) VALUES ('2019-01-05 14:30:00','2019-01-05 15:30:00','2019-01-05 16:30:00','2019-01-05 21:00:00', '3');

INSERT INTO tblassistance(Entrance, LunchExit, LunchEntrance, DayExit, UserID) VALUES ('2019-01-05 14:30:00','2019-01-05 15:30:00','2019-01-05 16:30:00','2019-01-05 20:10:00', '4');
```

The report needs to display the extra time for each user counting from 20:30 of each day limited to 21:30.

So far I've managed to (try to) sketch the following query:

```
(SELECT TIMEDIFF(DATE(tblassistance.DayExit) = CURDATE() && tblassistance.DayExit> (SELECT CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 21:30:00'))) GROUP BY tblassistance.userID, tblassistance.entrance
```

The original report is in a stored procedure format, which only receives an initial and final date, and also reports the number of days and other parameters unrelated to the present issue. If it's needed in order to solve the present issue (getting the TIMEDIFF() amount of extra time reported for a date) I can give further details.

Comment: Hi Ghaamae, the report only need to round to extra hours, ignoring minutes?

Comment: Your `INSERT` statements are broken : `ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count `

Comment: Hello Ass3mbler, the parameter that is needed to report is every 30 extra minutes, not less.

Comment: @GMB edited, sorry and thanks.

Comment: @Ghaamae, ok thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
        UserID, 
        GREATEST(
        "00:00:00", 
         TIMEDIFF( 
                  LEAST( DayExit, DATE_FORMAT( DayExit,  "%Y-%m-%d 21:30:00" ) ) , 
                  DATE_FORMAT( DayExit,  "%Y-%m-%d 20:30:00" ) 
                  ) 
                 )
FROM    `tblassistance`
```

Comment: It does give the extra time after 20:30, the problem is that I need the constraint to ignore the extra time after the 21:30 limit parameter

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand correctly your question, let me edit

Comment: Thank you very much @Ass3mbler, I have a new issue, hope you can help. It's for negative values:

SQLException: Bad format for Time '-08:31:23.000000'

Is there a way to avoid calculating extra time if it's not being reported after 20:30 ?

Comment: I just added an INSERT for a user who checked out at 20:10

Comment: Sure, I'll add the costrain

Comment: Now the query will give only 00:00:00 or bigger results. If it works, please accept the answer, thank you!

Comment: YAY! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Glad it helped, have a nice day! ;)